# Why can the gaussian curvature be computed this way?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces

> [image]
>
> [image]

I understood everything up to the last part ("It follows that the gaussian curvature $K = K(s, v)$ of the tube is given by..."). Why? What am I missing here? I know we can just compute it from the second fundamental form, but I want to understand what was done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are reading Do Carmo's book on Differential Geometry, aren't you?

If so, have a look at the discussion at page 166. There you see the equation
$$ dN(w_1) \wedge dN(w_2) = K w_1 \wedge w_2,$$
for a basis $\{w_1, w_2\}$ of a tangent space at a point. This is exactly what you need.

Comment: That solves it. Thanks!